# (python/pygame) sound stuttering and stopping

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have sounds working, in my game, pretty well. Except, if the sound is rapidly played, or multiple sounds overlap, only one of the sounds play and the rest are cut off. Is there a way to fix this?                I'm using:

```
pygame.mixer.Sound.play()
```

to play sounds.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you have the:

```
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Inside a loop. Try:

```
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.time.wait()#Inside the () of pygame.time.wait(), type the length of the audio in seconds,
```

That should do it!